# How to add android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout into intelliJidea?

Tags: android, intellij-idea, grid-layout, android-appcompat

I want to add GridLayout into my android project which is use support library GridLayout v7. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12468606/intellij-and-android-support-v7-widget-gridlayout/12477911#12477911) thread but maybe a few steps of adding this library did not mention in this paragraph **Set up support GridLayout library in IntelliJ**.

can anyone explain obviously?

**Edit:**
I have the same problem at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13160523/intellij-getting-gridlayout-work?rq=1) thread

Answer (score 47, accepted):

It's late for an answer but here it is, at least for future people looking for a solution on **how to add the support library and resources for `GridLayout`** (or `ActionBarActivity` / `AppCompat`, see below).

The easiest way is as follows.

1. Make sure you have installed the **Android Support Library**, from the Android SDK Manager.
   [image]
2. In IDEA: Open your project, then select `File` / `Import Module`

   - select the directory under the SDK: `{SDK}\extras\android\support\v7\gridlayout`
     [image]
   - select `Import module from external model` and `Eclipse`
   - you can then select `Create module files near .classpath files`, or choose to put them elsewhere if you can't / don't want to write into your SDK path
   - in the next screen you should see `Select Eclipse projects to import` and `android-support-v7-gridlayout`, IDEA will also ask you to reload the project.
   - this should add a module `gridlayout [android-support-v7-gridlayout]` in your project.
3. Now you have to update your project dependencies to this module for the resources, and add the .jar libraries. Select `File` / `Project Structure`

   - select the `Modules` project settings, and select your project (in the picture below, **testv7**)
   - select the `Dependencies` on the right panel
   - add with the `+` button (on the right panel) a `Module dependency...` to the `android-support-v7-gridlayout`
     [image]
   - similarly, add a `Jars or directories...` pointing to the `{SDK}\extras\android\support\v7\gridlayout\libs` directory (or to the .jar within). *If you intend to use the v4 as well, choose `{SDK}\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\libs` instead since it contains both v4 and v7 jars*
   - your settings should look like this:
     [image]

And now you should be fine.

For me it was the only way out of the similar problem with the `ActionBarActivity`, which is solved using the same technique on the `{SDK}\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat` module. And I did try a few other ways ;)

Comment: Thanks I just switched from Eclipse to IntelliJ and this helped me to add the appcompat library to the project I'm working on.

Comment: wow I spent the whole day trying to figure this out. I would give +5 if I could. Thanks for the thorough instructions.

Comment: You're welcome, that took quite some time to figure out too :)

Comment: Also: make sure you have enabled Eclipse Integration plugin (I never used it, and had it turned off, and couldn't understand why I have only gradle and flash to choose from) and make sure order of dependencies is set properly (I had library above module sources and it was failing with a weird error - on generating R.java). Also, for me adding libraries that way didn't work, I had to put them in the libs directory inside my main module (and then add them to dependencies). I can't believe how many traps it has...

Answer (score 16):

Today I struggled with this and on [android dev site](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html) I found simpler solution and why they're problems with it. GridLayout from v7 libraries aren't connected with v7 appcompat library so you must add v7 gridlayout library dependency manually.

If you use gradle then in `build.gradle` just add

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:23.1.+'
}
```

and everything should works fine :)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Android Studio, just go to Gradle Script -> build.gradle(Module:app) -> dependencies and type those dependencies there for better support.

```
compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:23.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
```

P/S the "v7:23.0.2" depends on your lastest build tools..

Hope this will help..

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.

Comment: He's not using Android Studio. He's using IntelliJ