# can not connect android-support-v7-appcompat to my project

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-appcompat

I downloaded an example from [`developer.android.com`](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html)

imported in `IntellijIDEA` and all up. Next, I wanted to connect the library `android-support-v7-appcompat` to my project. I did it according to instructions:

- [How to add android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout into
  intelliJidea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17292812/how-to-add-android-support-v7-widget-gridlayout-into-intellijidea)
- [Tutorial on youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XyaZEphsz44)

and many others. And in all cases I have the same error. When you compile the project `IntellijIDEA` says that there are no resources:

error screen http://www.fayloobmennik.net/4303361

```
Error:android-apt-compiler: [android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\Users\Pavel\Desktop\appcompat\res\values-v2
Error:android-apt-compiler: [android-support-v7-appcompat] 1\themes_base.xml:41: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material.Light.Dialog'.
Error:android-apt-compiler: [android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\Users\Pavel\Desktop\appcompat\res\va
Error:android-apt-compiler: [android-support-v7-appcompat] lues-v21\themes_base.xml:153: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
C:\Users\Pavel\Desktop\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml
Error:(75, -1) android-apt-compiler: [android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\Users\Pavel\Desktop\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:75: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton'.
Error:(79, -1) android-apt-compiler: [android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\Users\Pavel\Desktop\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:79: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton.CloseMode'.
Error:(83, -1) android-apt-compiler: [android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\Users\Pavel\Desktop\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:83: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton.Overflow'.
Error:(25, -1) android-apt-compiler: [android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\Users\Pavel\Desktop\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:25: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionBar.TabView'.
Error:(29, -1) android-apt-compiler: [android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\Users\Pavel\Desktop\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:29: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabView'.
Error:(33, -1) android-apt-compiler: [android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\Users\Pavel\Desktop\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:33: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionBar.TabText'.
Error:(37, -1) android-apt-compiler: [android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\Users\Pavel\Desktop\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:37: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabText'.
Error:(41, -1) android-apt-compiler: [android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\Users\Pavel\Desktop\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:41: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabText'.
Error:(65, -1) android-apt-compiler: [android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\Users\Pavel\Desktop\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:65: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionMode.Title'.
Error:(69, -1) android-apt-compiler: [android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\Users\Pavel\Desktop\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:69: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionMode.Subtitle'.
Error:(45, -1) android-apt-compiler: [android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\Users\Pavel\Desktop\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:45: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Menu'.
Error:(49, -1) android-apt-compiler: [android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\Users\Pavel\Desktop\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:49: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title'.
Error:(53, -1) android-apt-compiler: [android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\Users\Pavel\Desktop\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:53: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle'.
Error:(57, -1) android-apt-compiler: [android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\Users\Pavel\Desktop\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:57: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse'.
Error:(61, -1) android-apt-compiler: [android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\Users\Pavel\Desktop\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:61: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle.Inverse'.
Error:(178, -1) android-apt-compiler: [android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\Users\Pavel\Desktop\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:178: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ProgressBar.Horizontal'.
Error:(182, -1) android-apt-compiler: [android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\Users\Pavel\Desktop\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:182: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ProgressBar'.
Error:(113, -1) android-apt-compiler: [android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\Users\Pavel\Desktop\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:113: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Spinner'.
Error:(115, -1) android-apt-compiler: [android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\Users\Pavel\Desktop\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:115: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Spinner'.
Error:(110, -1) android-apt-compiler: [android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\Users\Pavel\Desktop\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:110: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.DropDownItem.Spinner'.
Error:(107, -1) android-apt-compiler: [android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\Users\Pavel\Desktop\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:107: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ListView.DropDown'.
Error:(121, -1) android-apt-compiler: [android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\Users\Pavel\Desktop\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:121: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ListView'.
Error:(126, -1) android-apt-compiler: [android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\Users\Pavel\Desktop\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:126: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ListPopupWindow'.
Error:(138, -1) android-apt-compiler: [android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\Users\Pavel\Desktop\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:138: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:overlapAnchor'.
Error:(143, -1) android-apt-compiler: [android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\Users\Pavel\Desktop\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:143: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:overlapAnchor'.
Error:(129, -1) android-apt-compiler: [android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\Users\Pavel\Desktop\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:129: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.PopupMenu'.
Error:(132, -1) android-apt-compiler: [android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\Users\Pavel\Desktop\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:132: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.PopupMenu'.
Error:(146, -1) android-apt-compiler: [android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\Users\Pavel\Desktop\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:146: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Large'.
Error:(150, -1) android-apt-compiler: [android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\Users\Pavel\Desktop\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:150: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Small'.
Error:(154, -1) android-apt-compiler: [android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\Users\Pavel\Desktop\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:154: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Large'.
Error:(158, -1) android-apt-compiler: [android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\Users\Pavel\Desktop\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:158: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Small'.
Error:(164, -1) android-apt-compiler: [android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\Users\Pavel\Desktop\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:164: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:TextAppearance.Material.SearchResult.Title'.
Error:(168, -1) android-apt-compiler: [android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\Users\Pavel\Desktop\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:168: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:TextAppearance.Material.SearchResult.Subtitle'.
Error:(172, -1) android-apt-compiler: [android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\Users\Pavel\Desktop\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:172: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.AutoCompleteTextView'.
Error:(174, -1) android-apt-compiler: [android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\Users\Pavel\Desktop\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:174: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.AutoCompleteTextView'.
Error:(93, -1) android-apt-compiler: [android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\Users\Pavel\Desktop\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:93: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Toolbar.Button.Navigation'.
Error:(97, -1) android-apt-compiler: [android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\Users\Pavel\Desktop\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:97: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title'.
Error:(101, -1) android-apt-compiler: [android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\Users\Pavel\Desktop\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:101: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle'.
C:\Users\Pavel\Desktop\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml
C:\Users\Pavel\Desktop\appcompat\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml
C:\Users\Pavel\Desktop\appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml
C:\Users\Pavel\Desktop\appcompat\res\values-v11\themes_base.xml
C:\Users\Pavel\Desktop\appcompat\res\values-v14\themes_base.xml
```

manifest

```
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.navigationdrawerexample"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: You should check your theme declaration.

Comment: Show your project manifest for others - I'm out now. For sure, project target version should be api 21 and Android 5 used I think. If not, change it, clean and try. "Maybe" it can help.

Comment: In this sample project target version is 17 `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="17" />` and here can be problem. Change it first to `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="21" />` in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: android:targetSdkVersion="21" did not help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your project, change Android Build Target to 5.0

To support values-v21, Your Build Target should be 5.0

---

Go to `File -> "Project Structure"`

Under `Platform Settings -> SDKs` you can see android sdk path, classpath and build target.

Update your sdk first with latest build target using sdk manager.

If you're sdk is not up-to date then in the classpath you can see android version below 21.

If you have latest one, then You can see, classpath selected to \android-21\android.jar.

or

In you're Module Settings you can see "Build Tool Version".

Android Studio (IntelliJ IDEA) will be taking latest build version. So first update you're sdk manager to latest version.

Comment: did not quite understand. in the manifest of the project or module to change?

Comment: OK, I'll update the SDK. be sure to write about the result. Look at my question a little later please, I really long plagued with this problem

Comment: all works. thank you very much. You save me 3 days)))) I am immensely grateful to you !!!!

Answer (score 0):

The Material style request Android Build Tools version 20+ and compile sdk version 21+. if you use Gradle build system,change compileSdkVersion 21 or higher inside the build.gradle file.

Comment: I do not use Gradle. if used, I think this question would not have arisen

Comment: @SergeyBalybin Try to open `Project Structure` dialog and change the `Project Sdk` to version 21.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you in your workspace, the android support lib existed.
2. Open your project properties, go to tab Android, and check the linked library is available or not.
   If the support library is marked red X, that means you should see your library link folder. This error occurs mostly when you put **the library and the source not the same workspace.**